# Best way to keep ci/cd server node_modules update without removing it?

Tags: javascript, npm, continuous-integration

One problem we have on our ci/cd server is that we always want to install the correct version of the node packages on the server, and we can not trust the `package-lock.json` because our source control locks this file, and sometimes the wrong file is on the server. On the other hand, **we can not delete the node_modules** and the **package-lock.json** because there are many client projects, and it takes a **long time for this process to end**.

One way we want to try is to execute `npm i && npm update`. Have you experienced this problem? What do you suggest for keeping the modules up to date and not deleting them?

Comment: Check out the `npm ci` command: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci

Comment: npm ci removes node_modules